# ActiveAndroid save only unique data

Tags: android, activeandroid

I Learn to use ActiveAndroid in my Android apps, Can anyone tell me how to save ONLY the data that have unique id? in my Model, I have set id as non Primary Key column. This is my Model Class :

```
package com.project.echo.contactmanagement.data;

import com.activeandroid.Model;
import com.activeandroid.annotation.Column;
import com.activeandroid.annotation.Table;
import com.activeandroid.query.Select;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

import java.util.List;


@Table(name="Contacts" , id = "idColumn")
public class Post extends Model {

@Expose
@Column(name = "ProfilePic")
public String profilePic;

@Expose
@Column(name = "id")
public Integer id;

@Expose
@Column(name = "FirstName")
public String firstName;

@Expose
@Column(name = "LastName")
public String lastName;

public Post()
{
    super();
}

public Post(String profilePic, Integer id, String firstName, String lastName)
{
    this.profilePic=profilePic;
    this.id=id;
    this.firstName=firstName;
    this.lastName=lastName;
}

public String getProfilePic() {
    return profilePic;
}


/*public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}*/


public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}


public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public static List selectAll() {
    return new Select().from(Post.class).execute();
}
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can insert unique record by making id column unique.

```
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, onUniqueConflict = Column.ConflictAction.REPLACE)
private Integer id;
```

**Note**: In ActiveAndroid, **com.activeandroid.Model** class already has a **column** named **id** so you might need to rename the id column in order to serve the purpose.